# How do I find the distance between two points?

Tags: python, math

Let's say I have x1, y1 and also x2, y2.

How can I find the distance between them?
It's a simple math function, but is there a snippet of this online?

Comment: It didn't work. So I asked here. I figured out why. It's coz I did ^ instead of **

Comment: @Greg: His track record says no.  @TIMEX: Searching didn't work?  Seriously: http://www.google.com/search?q=python+distance+points

Comment: -1 for "is there a snippet of this online?" Seriously, @TIMEX, if searching the web for a code snippet is too hard, now is the time for a change of career.

Comment: I'm surprised this question is closed. It was in my search results for 'python pythagoras' and was how I discovered the existence of math.hypot.

Comment: Okay, I just want to add a note that this *is* on the first page of google.  It always frustrates me to see "just google it" as the first answer.  Quite obviously there was some need that this question filled.

Comment: @GlennMaynard I came here by searching "python distance point", what do I do now?

Comment: Be wise, generalise "dist = numpy.linalg.norm(a-b)" where a and b are your two vectors.

Comment: A closed question yet so popular !!!!

Answer (score 150, accepted):

```
dist = sqrt( (x2 - x1)**2 + (y2 - y1)**2 )
```

As others have pointed out, you can also use the equivalent built-in [`math.hypot()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/math.html#math.hypot):

```
dist = math.hypot(x2 - x1, y2 - y1)
```

Comment: This is, by the way, the [distance formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance#Geometry)

Comment: did you mean http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance ?

Comment: This isn't how to do the "power" in python?  Isn't it **?

Comment: @TIMEX: Yes it is. The change is now reflected on @MitchWheat's post

Comment: I'm inclined to downvote this and all answers that ignore math.hypot because it seems wrong to reimplement code, however trivial, that is in the standard library. But instead, a question: is there any good reason to write the above code?

Comment: @RobFisher - explicitly writing this expression may actually be *faster* than calling `math.hypot` since it replaces a function call with inline bytecodes.

Answer (score 72):

Let's not forget math.hypot:

```
dist = math.hypot(x2-x1, y2-y1)
```

Here's hypot as part of a snippet to compute the length of a path defined by a list of (x, y) tuples:

```
from math import hypot

pts = [
    (10,10),
    (10,11),
    (20,11),
    (20,10),
    (10,10),
    ]

# Py2 syntax - no longer allowed in Py3
# ptdiff = lambda (p1,p2): (p1[0]-p2[0], p1[1]-p2[1])
ptdiff = lambda p1, p2: (p1[0]-p2[0], p1[1]-p2[1])

diffs = (ptdiff(p1, p2) for p1, p2 in zip (pts, pts[1:]))
path = sum(hypot(*d) for d in  diffs)
print(path)
```

Comment: Python3 no longer allows tuples as lambda parameter so the function become this:
        ptdiff = lambda p: (p[0][0]-p[1][0], p[0][1]-p[1][1])
        diffs = map (ptdiff , zip(pts[:-1],pts[1:]))
        path = sum(math.hypot(d1,d2) for d1,d2 in diffs)

Answer (score 18):

[image]
It is an implementation of Pythagorean theorem. Link: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_theorem