# Game ai Line of Sight Python

Tags: python, pyglet, game-ai

How would I check to see whether the player is within range of a mob? (I am making a top down game in pyglet) I am making it so that the mobs follow and attack the player if he is within a certain distance of them but I am unsure how to efficiently do this. Would I need to do an "if" statement to see if x > mob.x - 50 and x < mob.x + 50 etc?

I have a class for the mobs

```
class zombie(pyglet.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self, image, x, y, batch,trees):
            pyglet.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self, image, x, y, batch=None)
```

I then used several functions as the different actions they could be doing

```
    def move(self):
        ...
    def idle(self):
        ...
```

The player's position is "player.x" and "player.y" (the same for the mobs but with "zombie instead of player)

As Joran said, I think finding the distance betweens the mob and the player's coordinates is the best approach and I will make another function to check the distance.

Sorry if this was unclear

Comment: You have to show a sample of your code and explain your representation of the player's position, the mob, etc for this to be answerable.

Comment: duplicate:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5228383/how-do-i-find-the-distance-between-two-points

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you would probably need to calculate the distance between the monster and the player

```
sqrt((mob.x-player.x)**2 + (mob.y-player.y)**2)
```

you could probably simplify it and get rid of the sqrt ...

Comment: Thanks for the answer, finding the distance seems the simplest way