# Calculating distance between pixels in real time in python

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, image-processing

I'm a beginner in image processing. I want to detect eye movement from webcam using openCV in python. I'm using this code snippet for the detection of right eye:

```
eye_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_righteye_2splits.xml')
eyes = eye_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, minSize=(30, 30))

for (ex, ey, ew, eh) in eyes:
    cv2.rectangle(frame, (ex, ey), (ex+ew, ey+eh), (0, 255, 0), 2)

    print(str(ex)+'b'+str(ey))
    print("Sent\n")
```

It displays the pixels of my right eye in real time, like this:

```
.
.
.
260b216
Sent

261b219
Sent
.
.
.
```

I can see the pixel values change when I move my eyes, but I want python to calculate the distance between two consecutive pixel values: sqrt((261-260)^2 + (219-216)^2), and display this value as output, in real time. Which numpy/math/other functions do I have to use to achieve this?

Comment: You can use math.hypot() https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5228383/how-do-i-find-the-distance-between-two-points

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to calculate the euclidian distance between two consecutive frames. ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1401712/how-can-the-euclidean-distance-be-calculated-with-numpy))

You can initialize a counter `cnt` for counting the two consecutive frames. Each time you get the `(ex, ey, ew, eh)` increase the `cnt` by one. If you get the two consecutive frames calculate the distance between them and print.

To calculate the distance you need to store the previous coordinates (`exy_prv`) and current (`exy_cur`)

Here is an example code:

```py
import numpy as np

eyes = [[260, 216, 260 + 50, 216 + 50],
        [261, 219, 261 + 50, 219 + 50],
        [262, 222, 262 + 50, 222 + 50],
        [263, 224, 263 + 50, 224 + 50]]

cnt = 1
exy_prv = []
dist = None

for (ex, ey, ew, eh) in eyes:
    if cnt % 2 == 0:
        exy_cur = np.array((ex, ey))
        dist = np.linalg.norm(exy_cur - exy_prv)
        cnt = 1
        exy_cur = exy_prv

    # cv2.rectangle(frame, (ex, ey), (ex+ew, ey+eh), (0, 255, 0), 2)

    print(str(ex)+'b'+str(ey))
    print("Sent\n")

    if dist is not None:
        print("distance: {}\n".format(dist))

    exy_prv = np.array((ex, ey))
    cnt += 1
```

Result

---

```sh
260b216
Sent

261b219
Sent

3.1622776601683795

262b222
Sent

3.1622776601683795

263b224
Sent

2.23606797749979
```